# Adding a subdomain on Google Domains

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, lets-encrypt, txt-record, google-domains

I'm trying to create a TXT DNS record with name `_acme-challenge.www` on Google Domains to allow me to validate my DNS (i.e. via `_acme-challenge.www.example.com`).  I've already validated the domain itself; but want to validate the `www` subdomain so I can provide this in the certificate's Subject Alternative Name.  When attempting this, the page gives error: `Failed to save changes to domain settings for example.com`.

Is what I'm attempting valid / if so can anyone suggest what I may be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does work:

- Navigate to Google Domains (https://domains.google.com)
- Select the domain you wish to manage
- Click the `DNS` icon
- Scroll down to `Custom resource records`
- Fill out the fields above the column heads / by the `Add` button (below is example data; amend per your needs)

  - Name: _acme-challenge.www
  - Type: TXT
  - TTL: 1h
  - Data: ABCDEF blah blah blah
- Click `Add`

I'm not sure why this didn't work the first time I tried it as I think I did exactly the above; so putting this down to a glitch.  Recording here in case it's of use to others searching for similar.