# Unable to Create Valid Subdomain on Google Domains

Tags: ssl, subdomain, cname-record, lets-encrypt, txt-record

Hello all and thank you for your time.

I have a domain that is managed my Google Domains. I Added a subdomain as per Googles Documentation

[Screengrab - Google Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnRn4.png)

I have given it nearly 48 hours and I still cannot access the subdomain and / or add a cert to the subdomain ( Lets Encrypt states "DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for couchdb.livestalk.org - check that a DNS record exists for this domain" )

I checked https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?q=livestalk.org and it appears that the CNAME has been updated in the DNS but its showing Name Error?

[Screengrab - Name Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ke2S.png)

I also attempted to Add a Subdomain like John mentioned Here: [Adding a subdomain on Google Domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/888740/adding-a-subdomain-on-google-domains) but still had no luck...

Any recommendations on how to get the subdomain to work with Google Domains is greatly appreciated. Never had this issue with any other domain manager.

Comment: This all looks correct. What did Google say when you contacted them for support?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Its been a waiting game from Google Support ( I assume due to COVID ) currently. they only have linked me to the guide that I followed previously resulting in the above record. Currently I am awaiting a transfer to a different group since the server is hosted as a Google Compute VM. 

Serverfault is my plan B since support is taking to long and I was hoping that perhaps I did configure something incorrectly... I will keep the thread up to date if and when support responds.

Answer (score 0):

This does not fix the core issue but was a valid workaround for my use. I ended up creating a Google Cloud Domain Service to Bypass the Google Domain interface all together.

To do this, create a network cloud dns zone on the Google Cloud Platform https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns/zones ( I assume you could use AWS or any other service where you can configure Cloud DNS ) Once created, a NS Record will automatically be created with 4 Name Servers ( e.x. ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com ). Copy those name servers and go back to the Google Domains interface https://domains.google.com/registrar.

In Google Domains, under the DNS tab, select Use custom name servers and then paste in the Name Servers From above. It will give you some warnings, just click through the popups. Once updated, you can close the page as everything will now be managed by the newly created service above.

Once the DNS updated ( For me it took about an hour ) back int the newly created zone interface, I created a new CNAME record with the same params as I did before and everything resolved almost instantaneously.

Note : Since Google Domains is now bypassed, you will have to migrate any and all of your custom records from the Google Domains interface to your newly created service as well.

Its silly I had to point Google Domains to a custom Google Cloud Domains service in order to resolve a CNAME record properly but at least it got me up and running. Hope this saves someone some time when trying to set custom DNS records with a Google Domain hosted URL.